How do I use jsdoc to document a set of functions that destructured from the return value of another function?
Firstly, I have read this question/answer, and it doesn't quite apply to my situation.
I'm calling a library function, which dynamically creates and returns an array of functions. My module then exports those functions, so I want them to be documented. My code looks like like this:
import createFunctions from 'some-library'

/**
* What do I write here, to document `functionA` and `functionB`?
*/
const [functionA, functionB] = createFunctions('a', 'b');

// This doesn't seem to work:
/**
* Some docs
*/
functionA;

// This also doesn't seem to work:
/**
* Some docs
*/
export { functionA };

/**
* I don't know how this would work either
*/
export { functionA, functionB };

I don't control createFunctions, so I can't write doc comments inside it to describe the returned functions, as suggested in the other answer.
EDIT: I've already tried both of these approaches and they don't seem to work, at least vscode does not pick them up:




You could create a new js file just to define these functions and document them. Finally, document them on the correct place like the way you wanted. This way you have a complete documentation as well as comments on the place you want to :)

Ok I think I have figured it out. Unless anyone has a better solution, this seems to be the best workaround:
import createFunctions from 'some-library'

const [_functionA, _functionB] = createFunctions('a', 'b');

/**
* Some docs for functionA
*/
const functionA = _functionA;

/**
* Some docs for functionB
*/
const functionB = _functionB;

// Can either export all together like this, or put the
// export statements above as part of each declaration.
export { functionA, functionB };

